# Excel vba external reference

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have a general purpose workbook with all of my frequently used (ie common) macros.
Some time ago I discovered a way to include this file as an external reference in other workbooks which needed to call the common macros.
BUT I have forgotten how to do it.
I have a note I made stating 'use Tools, References' but cannot find a Tools option in the ribbon.
I am using excel Home & Student 2019.
I have searched online but can only find references to running specific macros.

Answer (score 0):

The option you're looking for is in the VBA Editor. Open it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> then use the Menu as shown:

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Owen. Don't know how I missed that.